# How to wait all post request

Tags: post, axios

I have multiple post requests like=>

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.selectedRowKeys.length; i++) {

      var rowid = this.state.selectedRowKeys[i];

      let savevalue = {
        id: rowid,            
      }
      queries.push(this.approve_leave(savevalue));
    }    


    Promise.all(queries).then(function (values) {
      console.log("done");         
    });

    this.selectData();
}

 approve_leave(savevalue) {       
    leave_api.leave_approve(savevalue).then(res => {         
      if (res.status === "fail") {           
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
  }
```

I called this post API request and after all post request is done, I just reselect from the database and show update record in the table.

But now after I click the save button,it shows not refresh data in the table but if I reload page its shows refresh data.

Promise.all is waited for all post requests but

For my situation, **why it does not wait for all request and go select?**

here is API request=>

```
export const leave_approve = leave => {
  return axios
    .put(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/leave/leave_approve/",
      { leave },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    )
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got into the promise loopback problem a while bac and now I just `asyn-await` for where all I need to do the above.

Sample :

```
async function something(){ // Should declare async in the method declaration to use await
// Below code waits till it is finished executing because we used await 
    await axios
    .put(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/leave/leave_approve/",
      { leave },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    )
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
}
```

https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: I changed like that but still not refresh.